# gdb can not set breakpoint at correct position

Tags: c, gdb

I am a starter to C and am trying to use gdb to debug a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i;
        i = 2;
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I use `gdb b main`, it did not work correctly:

```
PS F:\try> gcc -g -o try try.c
PS F:\try> gdb try
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from try...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401564: file try.c, line 4.
```

The breakpoint is set at line 4 however I suppose it should be set at the start of `main()`.
Even if I set this manually, when I run the program the breakpoint won't get hit:

```
PS F:\try> gcc -g -o try try.c
PS F:\try> gdb try
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.        
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from try...done.
(gdb) b 2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401564: file try.c, line 2.
(gdb) run
Starting program: F:\try\try.exe 
[New Thread 11464.0xbf8]
[New Thread 11464.0x508]

Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x181490) at try.c:4
4           i = 2;
```

As shown above I set a breakpoint at line 2 but it ran through line 4. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Breakpoints can only be set on statements that do something. Declarations don't do anything, so they're skipped over, and the breakpoint is put on the first executable statement, which is

```
i = 2;
```

Comment: Funnily enough, [this doesn't happen for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqrcY.jpg), which I find quite puzzling. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe it's version-dependent. You're using 9.2, the OP is using 8.1.

Comment: I just tried it with 10.1 and I reproduced the OP's results.

Comment: Hm then maybe it's the GCC version. I had 9.3.0. I used the exact same code and compiler command as the OP.

Comment: I'm using GCC 10.2.1.

Comment: @CherryDT Function `main` often has special handling. Is it the same for other functions?